# How do I align a grid to the bottom and place two buttons in the bottom right corner?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Beginner with WPF here. I am trying to make a window that has a panel in the bottom of the window, that contains two buttons side by side in the bottom right corner like in this picture:

[image: two buttons side by side in the bottom right corner]

but so far all I have managed to code is this:

[image: all I have managed to code]

The bottom panel is a mess. How do I make it look like my original design? I have tried dragging within the designer, but it is not working.

My XAML below (for the entire window - because I'm a noob. feel free to correct any mistakes).

```
<Window x:Class="ace.views.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ace.views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Welcome to My software " Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="top"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel Margin="30">
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="30" Foreground="#0078D7">Welcome to my software</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0 20">This application is here to help you to teach vocabulary to your students, and to keep track of their progress.</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0 20">Let's get started in the next step.</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid Background="#EFEFEF" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button  x:Name="cmdSubmit"
HorizontalAlignment="Center"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"  Width="120" Content="Next" />

            <Button x:Name="cmdReset"
HorizontalAlignment="Center"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"  Width="120" Content="Cancel" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two RowDefinitions in outer Grid should do the trick for Window layout.

Changing ColumnDefintions for inner Grid will help to pin buttons to the right side.

```
<Window x:Class="ace.views.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ace.views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="#EFEFEF" 
        Title="Welcome to My software " Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Margin="30">
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="30" Foreground="#0078D7">Welcome to my software</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0 20">This application is here to help you to teach vocabulary to your students, and to keep track of their progress.</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0 20">Let's get started in the next step.</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#EFEFEF">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button  x:Name="cmdSubmit" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"  Width="120" Margin="5" Content="Next"/>

            <Button x:Name="cmdReset" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2"  Width="120" Margin="5" Content="Cancel"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your first Grid from Top to Stretch.

```
   <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```

Put a Grid.RowDefinitions there...

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <RowDefinition Height="*" />
 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Your second Grid, point it to Grid.Row=1

```
 <Grid Background="#EFEFEF" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0">
```

To find out more about RowDefinitions, [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.rowdefinitions)

Comment: 'Stretch" is a default value for Alignment, they can be simply omitted in xaml

Comment: Yes,but it will be easier to visualize, specially in the begging... This is my opinion, helped some friends that was learning...